# What is the difference between -{minutes} and {minutes} when using the find command on Linux?

Tags: linux, find

My understanding of the following command is that it looks for files that have been modified in the last {x} minutes.

What does it mean if I exclude the `-` from `mmin`, what is it supposed to return?

**COMMAND**

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin -20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-mmin -20` returns files that are modified less than 20 minutes ago.

`-mmin 20` returns files that are modified exactly 20 minutes ago.

`-mmin +20` returns any file modified 20 minutes ago or older.

Comment: What do `-mmin +20 returns any file modified 20 minutes ago or older.` mean exactly? i.e. what is the difference between `-20 and +20`?

Comment: it will return files modified 30, 40, 50, .. minutes ago. If the file was modified N minutes ago, and N >= 20, then it will be included.

Answer (score 2):

From the [find(1) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```
Numeric arguments can be specified as

+n
    for greater than n,

-n    
    for less than n,

 n    
    for exactly n.

-mmin n
    File's data was last modified n minutes ago.
```

i.e., `-mmin -n` means the data is modified less than `n` minutes ago and `-mmin n` means the data is modified exactly `n` minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

The minus is for 'or less'.  '-mmin 20' will give you files modified exactly 20 minutes ago. `mmin -20` gives you files modified 0 to 20 minutes ago.